# Solving an equation with Reduce

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

In the equation shown in the code that follows, I must find or eliminate `rb`, but Mathematica is reluctant to work with my `Reduce` expression. Am I doing something wrong? Logarithms should always be positive.

```
Reduce[
  qb == 
   (ta - tb) / 
     (ri ((1/(ri*hi)) + log[(re/ri)/k] + log[(rb/re)/k0] + (1/(re*he)))) && 
   ri != 0 && hi != 0 && re != 0 && he != 0 && k != 0 && k0 != 0 && 
   rb != 0 && rb/(k0 re) > 0 && re/(k ri) > 0, rb] // FullSimplify
```

Comment: Do you mean [R](https://cran.r-project.org) or something else within *Mathematica*?

Comment: I suppose you should use `Log` instead of `log`. Built-in functions start with a capital, even standard math functions.

Comment: In WL, `Log[]`, not `log[]`.

Comment: Does `Reduce[..., rb, Reals]` give you what you need?

Comment: @Michael E2 ,Thanks, no more talk, I spent a long time reviewing and revising, a silly.
(how can I achieve an algebraic result without the restrictions that Reduce tells me to?)

Comment: The left hand side, the numerator, the denominator, and the Logs can each be zero or not. That can give you a forest of `ConditionalExpression` in an answer. IF you can justify that the denominator is not zero and cross multiply that then `Solve[Simplify[qb(ri((1/(ri*hi))+Log[(re/ri)/k]+Log[(rb/re)/k0]+(1/(re*he))))==(ta-tb),
ri!=0&&hi!=0&&re!=0&&he!=0&&k!=0&&k0!=0&&rb!=0&&rb/(k0 re)>0&&re/(k ri)>0],rb]` gives you a result with a single `ConditionalExpression` that the imaginary part lies in an interval. I believe that is because we do not even know that any of your variables are Real.

Comment: With the cross multiply, but without any of your other assumptions, the `Solve[Simplify[...]]` instantly gives you the single `ConditionalExpression` solution in almost the same form so the form of your assumptions don't seem to be helping very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Assuming[Element[ri | hi | he | k | k0 | qb | re | ta | tb, Reals] && 
  re/(k ri) > 0 && he != 0 && re != 0 && hi != 0 && qb != 0 && ri != 0, 
 Solve[qb == (ta - tb)/(ri (1/(he re) + 1/(hi ri) 
              + Log[rb/(k0 re)] + Log[re/(k ri)])), rb] // FullSimplify]
```

yields

```
{{rb -> E^(-(1/(he re)) - (qb - hi ta + hi tb)/(hi qb ri)) k k0 ri}}
```